# Принципы обработки UDP пакетов

Tags: udp, протоколы

Мне необходимо детально разобраться в том, **как работает обработка UDP пакетов**, начиная с момента получения кадров и заканчивая получением данных клиентским приложением.

Насколько я понимаю, происходит следующее:

Адаптер сетевой карты получает входящий кадр и помещает его в свой стэк обработки. Далее, когда дошла очередь да данного кадра, он начинает двигаться вверх до транспортного уровня и прикладного уровня, причем на промежутке между ними существуют собственные очереди(уже на уровне ОС). Когда он дойдет до прикладного уровня, пакет(изначально кадр(или несколько кадров)) будет развернут и передан клиентскому приложению, которое его обработает.

Мне хотелось бы детализировать и уточнить данную схему. Если она в чем-то некорректна - очень бы хотел услышать правки.

Нужна очень детальная схема.

В открытых источниках, к сожалению, найти ничего не удается.

Comment: посмотрите на реализацию сетевого стека в любом из свободных проектов: *gnu/linux*, *\*bsd*, *minix* и т.п.

Comment: Интересует виндовая реализация.